# Как найти в тексте ссылку такого вида example.com и заменить её на http://example.com?

Tags: php

Как найти в тексте ссылку такого вида example.com и заменить её на http://example.com?
Используя php.

Например в тексте:
Вот хорошая статья mysite.com/index.html?id=757

А заменить на:
Вот хорошая статья http://mysite.com/index.html?id=757

Comment: найди в строке ".com/", после найди пробел перед началом ссылки отталкиваясь от ".com/" и вставь туда "http://"

Comment: Не подойдёт, вдруг в тексте в ссылке уже стоит http, а тут я ещё добавлю

Comment: Только .com? Хороших статей не бывает в доменах .org или .net? А в .ru, .en, .de и еще более чем в сотне национальных доменов? А в доменах в национальных кодировках, например, .рф? А кириллические ссылки в формате punycode, вроде http://xn--80aealotvcjpi6j.xn--p1ai ?

Comment: Как вы собираетесь отличать ссылки от названий, похожих на ссылки. Например: "на сайте getpaint.net можно скачать программу paint.net - отличный графический редактор" - тут paint.net не является ссылкой, хотя сайт paint.net существует.

Comment: Я для примера привёл .com, может быть любой не только .com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно искать соответствия для слов, написанных латиницей, и разделённых точкой. Но как справедливо сказано в комментариях, это не обязательно может быть именно url, поэтому полагаться на такой подход на сто процентов нельзя:

```
$str = 'Текст example.com.com текст http://example.com';

$patt = '~
    (?:https?://)?        # Не обязательное вхождение <http://> или <https://>
    (
        (?:www\.)?        # Необязательное тройное <www> с точкой <.>
        (?:\pL{3,}\.)+    # Одна и более группа из символов: <3 и более буквы с точкой>
        \pL{2,4}(?=\s|\b) # От 2-х до 4-х букв с пробелом или границей
    )
~ix';

$str = preg_replace($patt, 'https://$1', $str);

echo $str;
```

---

Результат:

```
Текст https://example.com.com текст https://example.com
```

[**Демо**](https://regex101.com/r/jZJptI/6)